# rails before_action not in extended classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, before-filter

In `app/controllers/application_controller`

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :set_locale_or_redirect
    before_action :set_locale
```

That code is executed in all controllers. However, I don't want `set_locale_or_redirect` and `set_locale` to execute in `app/controllers/biblio_controller.rb` I tried this:

```rb
class Dts::BibliosController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :set_locale_or_redirect, raise: false
    skip_before_action :set_locale, raise: false
```

no success.

Comment: Don't use `before_filter`, it's deprecated, always use `before_action`.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. To 'skip' an before_action in a controller, you can use:

```
skip_before_action :action_name
```

In your case, it would be:

```
skip_before_action :set_locale_or_redirect
skip_before_action :set_locale
```

You can read more [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)